# using cx_oracle in ml-engine results in "Oracle Client library cannot be loaded"

Tags: cx-oracle, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to use cx_oracle in a google cloud ml-engine job but i'm not able to find how to make the instant client libraries available.

I packaged the task so that the libraries are in the package but 
still no luck.

Essentially IIUC i should set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but seems not possible in the ml-engine job.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi, Are you trying to create a training job or a prediction job? I am guessing training.
what error do you get when you packaged the module in the task? Also, curious: what are you trying to achieve with cx_oracle? Are you connecting to an oracle database as part of your  job?

Comment: Hi, I'm creating a training job. 

The error is "DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".

Comment: We have the features for the job available in a database and we would like use cx_oracle (with pandas, btw) to consume the data as we do on premises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your own container on Cloud ML Engine via the [custom container feature](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/custom-containers-training) to customize env variables.

Comment: Definitely true. 
I would have hoped for something less invasive but a custom container works.  The official documentation is easy to follow https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/custom-containers-training